# exception: unknown encoding: GBK on kivy on android

Tags: android, python, kivy

Through the use of the function `network.UrlRequest` in order to retrieve something from the website. The return value contains Chinese character. All the data is not encoded by `UTF8`, alternatively it is decoded with the use of `GBK` first and then encoded with `UTF8`; so the data can be processed smoothly.The code runs well on windows, but after exporting into an APK and deploying it on  my android device, an exception occurred.

I also tried to decode with `UTF8` directly, or decode with `gb1830` type, they resulted in failure.

```
def getDataByUrl(self, novalname, search_url):
    search = {'searchkey':novalname}
    search = urllib.urlencode(search)
    newurl = search_url + "?" + search      
    self.request = UrlRequest(newurl, self.res)     

def res(self,*args):        
    try:        
        data = self.request.result.decode('GBK').encode('utf8')
    except Exception, e:

        print 'bbg: exception:', str(e)

bbg: exception: unknown encoding: GBK
```

the same as decode with GB1830 ,
decode directory with utf8 also failed.

when I run on windows, the data will be like this:

< title>笔 < /title>

I wonder if there is no `GBK` type in android ?